# C++ convert "HH:MM:SS.fraction" to int64_t

Tags: c++, timedelta

Is there a common, convenient, cross-platform method for converting a string of format "HH:MM:SS.<fraction of a second>" to a (timedelta) numeric type and vice versa in C or C++?

Comment: take a look here, please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3414509/date-time-parsing-in-c

Comment: I was given to understand that strptime was POSIX only. Is it otherwise? As for boost, I'll have to do some reading...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strptime` is as portable as it gets for this particular problem.  It is not in the C standard library (even if it had been added since C89, C99 and C2011 are no more portable than POSIX (thanks ever so much, Microsoft)) but it's widespread enough that my recommendation is to write your code as if it were universal, then detect its absence in your build system and inject a replacement.  You can get a BSD-licensed replacement here: http://cvsweb.netbsd.org/bsdweb.cgi/src/lib/libc/time/strptime.c?rev=HEAD (may require portability tweakage)

Comment: Note that neither [`strftime()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strftime.html) for formatting nor [`strptime()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strptime.html) for parsing times supports fractional seconds according to POSIX. The Linux documentation (e.g. http://linux.die.net/man/3/strptime) also seems to have this limitation. The reasons for that: `struct tm` does not do fractions; there are many sub-second formats (`struct timespec`, `struct timeval`, ...) and you need both the numerator and the denominator for the fraction to be usable.

Answer (score 2):

It is not TERRIBLY hard (I'm assuming your time is machine generated, not hand-written, so we can rely on it being "correct" - otherwise, we'd have to add a load of "is this value in range" checks). I'm also going to assume that fraction is always the same number of digits.

```
int64_t parsetime(char *str)
{
    int hh, mm, ss, fract;
    int64_t t;

    if (sscanf(str, "%d:%d:%d.%d", &hh, &mm, &ss, &fract) != 4)
    {
        printf("Badly formed time %s\n", str);
        return -1;
    }

    // 1000000 assumes there are 6 digits in fract, and we want microseconds.
    t = ((hh * 60)  + mm *60) + s) * 1000000 + fract;

    return t;
}
```

You could do something similar, using a `double` and `%d:%d:%lf` for the format string, then multiply by the releveant multiplier to get your fractions into integer form (e.g. 1000 for milliseconds, 1000000 for micro, 100000000 for nanoseconds, etc)

Comment: Thanks. I wrote my own routine because in fact my format is `[[HH:]MM:]SS[.<fraction>]`